# Python create instance of derived class

Tags: python, reflection

I want to have abstract class Task and some derived classes like TaskA, TaskB, ...
I need static method in Task fetching all the tasks and returning list of them. But problem is that I have to fetch every task differently. I want Task to be universal so when I create new class for example TaskC it should work without changing class Task. Which design pattern should I use?
Let's say every derived Task will have decorator with its unique id, I am looking for function that would find class by id and create instance of it. How to do it in python?

Comment: does the static method NEED to be in the base class? or can it be a separate thing?

this sounds like a factory pattern.

Comment: I would like it to be in base class. I belive it is possible using reflections. I can get all derived classes using \_\_subclasses__, but I don't know how to check if class has decorator with specific id.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could achieve this.

the first and most simple is using the `__new__` method as a factory to decide what subclass should be returned.

```
class Base:
    UUID = "0"
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if args == "some condition":
            return A(*args, **kwargs)
        elif args == "another condition":
            return B(*args, **kwargs)

class A(Base):
    UUID = "1"

class B(Base):
    UUID = "2"
    
instance = Base("some", "args", "for", "the", condition=True)
```

in this example, if you wanted to make sure that the class is selected by uuid. you can replace the if condition to read something like

```
if a.UUID == "an argument you passed":
    return A
```

but it's not really useful. since you have knowledge of the specific UUID, you might as well not bother going through the interface.

since I don't know what you want the decorator for, I can't think of a way to integrate it.

**EDIT TO ADDRESS THE NOTE:**

you don't need to have update it every time, if you do your expressions smartly.

let's say that the defining factor comes from a config file, that says "use class B"

```
for sub_classs in self.__subclasses__():
    if sub_class.UUID == config.uuid:
        return sub_class(*args, **kwargs) # make an instance and return it
```

the problem with that is that uuid is not useful to us as people. it would be easier to understand if instead we used a `config.name` to replace every place we have uuid in the example

Comment: Problem with that is that you have to make condition in Base class. For example when you create new derived class you have to remember to add new condition to Base.

Comment: updated to answer the note a little bit more

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with this a lot of time and this is exactly what I wanted:

```
def class_id(id:int):
    def func(cls):
        cls.class_id = lambda : id
        return cls
    return func

def find_subclass_by_id(cls:type, id:int) -> type:
    for t in cls.__subclasses__():
        if getattr(t, "class_id")() == id:
            return t


def get_class_id(obj)->int:
    return getattr(type(obj), "class_id")()



class Task():
    def load(self, dict:Dict) -> None:
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(dict:Dict) -> 'Task':
        task_type = int(dict['task_type'])
        t = find_subclass_by_id(Task, task_type)
        obj:Task = t()
        obj.load(dict)
        return obj


    @staticmethod
    def fetch(filter: Dict):
        return [Task.from_dict(doc) for doc in list_of_dicts]

@class_id(1)
class TaskA(Task):
     def load(self, dict:Dict) -> None:
        ...
     ...
```